# Gatling SBT execute a specific simulation

Tags: scala, gatling

If you execute "sbt gatling:test" it runs all simulations it can find. Is there a way to pass an argument so that it just executes a specific simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run specific simulation like this:

```
sbt "gatling-it:testOnly com.mycompany.myapp.TestB"
```