# Cannot pass arguments using sbt to gatling simulation

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, simulation, gatling

Regarding to [Gatling SBT execute a specific simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401756/gatling-sbt-execute-a-specific-simulation) topic is there any way to pass argument to simulation?

I've been trying passing command from any CLI like:

```
sbt -Dx=1 -Dy=2 -Dz=3 "gatling:testOnly fooSimulation"
```

and:

```
sbt "-Dx=1 -Dy=2 -Dz=3 gatling:testOnly fooSimulation"
```

and all similar variations, but in result it gives just a **null** value.

Same thing I was trying to do in **sbt shell**, because I use it as well, but no success at all. Maybe my specific configuration in **build.sbt** is the main reason why it doesn't work. Nevertheless I do not want to pass the arguments in config file, it should be dynamic.

**build.sbt**

```
name := "Gatling"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)

fork := true

scalacOptions := Seq(
  "-encoding", "UTF-8", "-target:jvm-1.8", "-deprecation",
  "-feature", "-unchecked", "-language:implicitConversions", "-language:postfixOps")

libraryDependencies += "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.3.1" % Test
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.3.1" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" % "json4s-native_2.12" % "3.6.7" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.2.2.jre8" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter" % "2.3.5.RELEASE" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.1" % Test

Test / javaOptions += "-DpropertiesFile=./src/test/resources/application.properties"
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "3.2.0")
```

**Example code:**

```
class FooSimulation extends Simulation {

  before {
    println(s"x=${System.getProperty("x")}")
    println(s"y=${System.getProperty("y")}")
    println(s"z=${System.getProperty("z")}")
  }

  setUp(
    scenario("Foo")
      .exec( foo chain builder )
      .inject( foo injection )
  ).protocols( foo protocol )
}
```

Additionally my sbt shell is running with prefix **sbt:gatling**, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Note: your Gatling 3.3 is super obsolete. You should upgrade. Latest release is 3.7.6 as of now.

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Answer (score 0):

`sbt -Dx=1 -Dy=2 -Dz=3 "gatling:testOnly fooSimulation"` is correct.

But the modern sbt syntax is `sbt -Dx=1 -Dy=2 -Dz=3 "Gatling/testOnly fooSimulation"`.

If it doesn't work, you probably have a typo somewhere, or possibly your version of sbt and Gatling are way too old and your should upgrade.

Comment: Sbt version is 1.4.9 and I've tried that example (of course with proper params and simulation) multiple times.

Comment: No idea what your issue is. I've used https://github.com/gatling/gatling-sbt-plugin-demo/blob/main/src/test/scala/computerdatabase/BasicSimulation.scala, added a println(System.getProperty("foo")) and ran `sbt -Dfoo=bar "Gatling/testOnly computerdatabase.BasicSimulation"`. Worked like a charm.